# Symfony store url parameters in sessions

Tags: symfony, session, url, get, parameter-passing

Accessing messages page in a symfony project as follows.

```
  function messageNavigate(hotelid) {
             window.open('message/'+senderid+'','_blank')
  }
```

Here it is checking whether user logged in or not. If not, user redirect to login page. My problem is how to redirect him after login for the message page with the previously selected itemid.

routing.yml

```
message:
    path:     /message/{itemid}
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Message:message }   

login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Security:login}
```

seciurity.yml

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false  
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            default_target_path: /message/{itemid}
        provider: our_db_provider
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: /login
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking user login info and redirecting to login page manually, do something like this in message controller:

```
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');
```

This will redirect to login page if user is not logged in. It will also redirect back to original route after user submits login form.

Alternatively, you could probably set this attribute in session:

```
_security.main.target_path
```

To the URI where you want user to be redirected after login.